# How do I make selection highlighting work properly in Office 2010 applications?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

I run Windows-7 64-bit with Office 2010.  For some odd reason if I select text in any of the Office apps the selected text is not highlighted consistenly.  It is selected properly (i.e. I can copy or move the text correctly) but the highlighting oftentimes doesn't reflect it.

Do you know the fix or how to troubleshoot?

Here's a screenshot example:

[image]

P.S.  I already updated my Intel HD graphics drivers to the latest so no need for that suggestion :-(